# Nondimensionalize this equation and find the constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, dimensional-analysis

There is an initial value problem where $\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-\frac{N}{k}), N(0)=N_0$. I recognize this to be a logistic growth problem. I want to determine the dimensions of $r$ and nondimensionalize the equation. I know that the variavles are $N$ and $t$, so I should substitute a new variable for it to nondimensionalize right? What do I do next here?

Comment: Let $N$ have dimensions $L^{\alpha} T^{\beta}$ for arbitrary $\alpha, \beta$ to be determined, so that $N \to L^{\alpha} T^{\beta} N$. Then, using that $d/dt$ has units $L/T$, substituting into the ODE yields $$L^{\alpha+1} T^{\beta-1} \frac{dN}{dt} = \frac{r L^{\alpha} T^{\beta} N(k - L^{\alpha} T^{\beta} N)}{k}$$ Now try to determine the units of $r, k$ so that the units of time and length on the left hand side match the unites of time and length on the right hand side.

Comment: @mattos I tried it and couldn't get it to work. Could you provide another hint? Thanks.